# Prevent exit() in third-party function from exiting?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm calling several functions (which I can't edit) in sequence, but some of the functions redirect the user, so I never get to the next one.

I'm calling a third-party function which has calls to `wp_redirect()` which I'm able to prevent, but then the next line is `exit;` which I can't figure out how get around.

I was hoping to get around it with the `ob_` functions, but no luck so far.

Any suggestions, hacky or otherwise, will be hugely appreciated!

edit: I have an idea I haven't tried yet - somehow spawning off new processes to perform these tasks - what would be best way to do that, waiting for each to complete before moving on.

Comment: There's probably a reason why those other functions are calling exit and if you do figure out a way to get around it then you may end up breaking the 3rd party programs. That being said, you could [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to get around the problem but that assumes that there's only 1 exit called.

Comment: @apokryfos They call exit solely because they redirect. Can you go into more detail about using `register_shutdown_function()`?

Comment: It's a function that is called just before PHP is shut down e.g. when a script calls exit or die or when the script finishes executing normally. However, any exit called within the shutdown function will be are real exit, no more shutdown functions will be triggered from it. The manual pages are probably as much detail as you need for it. And yes, it's possible the other functions require the redirect to happen and will not complete successfully if it doesn't happen.

Comment: Okay thanks. I know what the redirects are for, I don't need to allow them to happen. It's a UX thing, and I'm automating the process so they're moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with using cURL to make three synchronous requests to a file with different GET params.

Answer (score 3):

I believe is possible to get the source code of the php interpreter ... mess with the exit function and then recompile and install on the web server your new custom version of php ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you just can't. There is an option to redefind native php function, see [runkit_function_redefine](https://www.php.net/runkit_function_redefine).

But in the comments it also says:

> language constructs
> (eval, die, exit, isset, unset, echo etc.) which might be confused
> with functions, cannot be renamed or redefined even with
> runkit.internal_override.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `runkit_function_redefine`. You'll need to make sure you can modify internal functions in your php.ini file in order to be able to change native/internal functions.

I think the php.ini setting you need to ensure is switched on is `runkit.internal_override`.

I've not tested this.

However, since `exit` is a language construct I'm not even sure it's possible to get around it even with the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception in wp_redirect, and wrap the code with try-catch statement, then check if the exception message contains the message you have set and return the response accordingly, I have used this hack with most plugins including woocommerce, ultimatemember etc...

example:

```
ob_start();
try{
    whatever code....
}catch(\Exception $e){
}
echo ob_get_clean();
```